# Writing data in Service Worker to Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm working on a Firebase project and I want to receive firebase cloud messages (send from a Node.js server) in my service worker in my javascript project. This works fine, but now I want to save some data in my firebase cloud firestore from my service worker after receiving the notification. And there is the problem, I'm running in the error listed below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined at Ln. (xmlhttp.js:167) at Me (channelrequest.js:512) at Ce (webchannelbase.js:1249) at Kn.xa (webchannelbase.js:1251) at re (run.js:124)

Since a few days I'm trying to find the error, but could not find a solution until now. Therefore I hope that you can help me now. I've tried to save the data in the firebase realtime database which works, but because I need to have offline persistence, I had to switch to cloud firestore which runs in the error above.

Here is the code from my node.js server for sending the notification (userID and registrationToken is defined before):

```
payload = {
     data: {
     "title": "This is a Notification",
     "body": "This is the body of the notification message."
     },
};

options = {
     priority: "high",
     timeToLive: 7200
};

// send message to the registration token
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, payload, options).then(function(response) {
     admin.firestore().collection("Logging").doc(userID).set({active: "true"});
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Error sending message:", error);
});
```

And here is the code for receiving the notification in my firebase-messagins service worker file (userID is defined before):

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  const keepAlive = async() => {
      firebase.firestore().collection("Logging").doc(userID).update({"open": "true"}); 
  }
  event.waitUntil(keepAlive()); 
});
```

Can anyone help me, please? I have no more ideas for solving my problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `XMLHttpRequest` inside of a service worker. Instead, you need to use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Based on your code, it's the Firebase client library that's using `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood. I don't think that you have any control over that (at least not based on what I see in the current JavaScript documentation for Firebase).

Instead of using the Firebase client library in your service worker, you could try using the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) directly, using `fetch()` to send your HTTP requests. You'll be responsible for things like authentication and setting whatever user ids, etc. that the client library would otherwise handle for you, but I think that's your best bet inside of a service worker.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 9 the Firebase Web SDK uses `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. So it works inside a service worker.