# Saving firebase notification inside service worker or server?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have just implemented the firebase notification in reactjs app using service worker. Everything is working just fine. I am able to receive notification in bothe foreground and background and even when the browser has been closed. But I personally don't like notifications popping up on browser. I like to show them inside the app itself.

So my question is, when the app is not running on a device, and a notification is issued to that device, should I save this notification to firestore to display it later in the app by writing code in service worker. Or is it better to save the notification at the server itself before even sending it to device. Or is there any third way that doesn't need to save the notification in the database?

Below is my service worker:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    databaseURL: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  /* I want to do something like this:
     firebase.db.collection("notifications").save(payload);
     Or should do above thing at the server itself?
*/
fetch('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/gratis-3ce5a/databases/(default)/documents/users',{
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      "fields": {
        "Name": {
          "stringValue": "Freshpak Rooibos Tea 80Pk"
        },
        "Description": {
          "stringValue": "Enjoy a cup of Freshpak Rooibos your no 1 Rooibos tea."
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(res=>res.json()).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', event => {
  console.log(event)
  return event;
});
```

This is the thing that I have been confused about for a very long time.

Please help me to find the better approach!!

Comment: I would save it in the setBackgroundMessageHandler to the firebase database.
And if the app is running you can query this database and show it.

Comment: Thats what is not happening. I have updated the code. Please see it.

Comment: What do you mean with "this does not happen"? Does the fetch not work?

Comment: I have found this question about saving firebase data inside service worker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261382/writing-data-in-service-worker-to-cloud-firestore -> It seems fetch should generally work.